# Как вывести пагинацию Laravel

Tags: laravel

Как вывести пагинацию при такой записи?

```
$messages = DB::table('dialog_messages')
->leftJoin('user_attributes','user_attributes.user_id','=','dialog_messages.user_id')
->select('user_attributes.avatar','user_attributes.fullname','dialog_messages.replay','dialog_messages.created_at','user_attributes.user_id','dialog_messages.id')
->where('dialog_messages.dialog_id','=', $request->dialog_id)
->orderBy('dialog_messages.id','DESC')->paginate(15)->reverse()->values();
```

если убираю

```
->reverse()->values()
```

то выводит

```
current_page: 1
data: [,…]
0: {avatar: "uploads/users/avatars/1-2020-02-05-223757.jpg", fullname: "Максим Дроздов", replay: "111111",…}
1: {avatar: "uploads/users/avatars/1-2020-02-05-223757.jpg", fullname: "Максим Дроздов",…}
first_page_url: "http://bet.litesites.ru/profile/dialogs/messages?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 3
last_page_url: "http://bet.litesites.ru/profile/dialogs/messages?page=3"
next_page_url: "http://bet.litesites.ru/profile/dialogs/messages?page=2"
path: "http://bet.litesites.ru/profile/dialogs/messages"
per_page: 15
prev_page_url: null
to: 15
total: 44
```

Comment: Правильно выводит, так как метод `paginate` оборачивает Ваши данные в `data` нужно применить данные методы (reverse ...) к массиву data и далее присвоить их к исходному массиву (Типо такого: ...$data = $messages['data']->reverse... )

Comment: при такой записи выдает message: "Call to a member function reverse() on null"
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"

Comment: dd($messages['data']) выдает null  а атк вообще не видит dd($messages->data)

Answer (score 0):

сделал так

```
$data = $messages->reverse()->values();
return response()->json([
   'messages' => $data,
   'page' => $messages->currentPage(),
]);
```